# Is it possible to use open liberty with jakarta package namespace?

Tags: jakarta-ee, open-liberty

I have an environment that already depends on jakarta.persistence packages for JPA. Is there a way to use jakarta.persistence packages with open liberty? All the tutorials I have seen so far still seem to depend on javax- instead of jakarta-namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I didn't yet have chance to try it, you could try OpenLiberty beta which supports Jakarta 9 EE. Check this post for more details - [Open Liberty beta is Jakarta EE 9 compatible](https://openliberty.io/blog/2021/03/05/jakarta-ee-9-compatibility.html)

Comment: Minutes after posting my question I found [this](https://openliberty.io/blog/2021/03/17/eclipse-transformer.html).

Comment: See also my presentation video here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEciyzi8baU

Comment: I tried to run a simple project with openliberty-jakartaee9, version 21.0.0.8-beta. Because it is a new project I rather put up the project manually and did not use the transformer mentioned in the comments above. I followed the recommendation to add a dependency to pom.xml and also set my liberty-maven-plugin to use version 3.3.5-M2. However the plugin could not resolve jakarta ee 9 features such as servlet-5.0. Any ideas what I am missing?